# systemd-networkd-wait-online.service check connection or hw ready?

Tags: networking, systemd

In systemd, there is a service:
`systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`

Does it check if the Internet connection is ready or NIC HW ready for Internet connection?

Comment: Just in case you have any idle NICs on bootup (which would cause the service to hang), here are the instructions to modify the service - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217252/boot-process-hangs-at-systemd-networkd-wait-online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From manpage,

> By default, it will wait for all links it is aware of and which are managed by systemd-networkd.service(8) to be fully configured or failed, and for at least one link to be online. Here, online means that the link's operational state is equal or higher than "degraded".

"degraded" mean the link has carrier and addresses valid on the local link configured. You can set what condition you want to mark as online `--operational-state=`. Possible higher values are enslaved
(the link has carrier and is enslaved to bond or bridge master network interface) and routable (the link has carrier and routable address configured). None of them means *internet connetion* because your router or what your NIC is connected to may doesn't have internet connection itself. But `routable` does means it is in a network.

Comment: a link has carrier means a link with a cable connected to another side?